# CDN is serving images on some pages but not on others

Tags: html, content-management-system, cdn, image-optimization

I have some issues trying to troubleshoot an issue on a website.

The CDN (content delivery network) is working some pages but not on other pages, I first thought it was due to a writting error on the path but it's not.

Example, Not working here (Homepage:

```
<div class="container">

<div class="row wrap">
    
<article class="col-sm-3 entry animate__animated animate__fadeInUp" aria-label="" style="height: 417px;">
 
<a class="thumb_link aligncenter" href="https://example.com/the-link/" title="click to read">

<img style="" class="entry-image attachment-post lazyloaded thumb img-responsive" alt="text" src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/img.png"><header class="entry-header"><h2 class="entry-title">Title</h2></header></a>
```

But it's working on another page (same posts, same image) (using Ezoic CDN as an example) (Custom page where all the recently pusblished posts are shown)

```
<div class="news-snippet"><a href="https://example.com/the-link/" rel="bookmark" class="featured-image">

<img src="https://sf.ezoiccdn.com/ezoimgfmt/example.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/img.png?ezimgfmt=rs:368x246/rscb1/ngcb1/notWebP" alt="text" ezimgfmt="rs rscb1 src ng ngcb1" class=" ezlazyloaded" data-ezsrc="https://sf.ezoiccdn.com/ezoimgfmt/example.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/image.png?ezimgfmt=rs:368x246/rscb1/ngcb1/notWebP" height="494" width="740" ezoid="0"></a>

<div class="summary">

<h4 class="news-title"><a href="https://example.com/the-link/" rel="bookmark">Title</a></h4><p>excerpt of post</p><a href="https://example.com/the-link/" rel="bookmark" class="readmore">Read More</a></div></div>
```

Why could this be happening?

I checked the path was correct as it appears in Wordpress an everything looks fine.

The location of the path is not the issue since the same image is getting optimized on a different page.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not using the CDN in the first example. Maybe you removed the content from the origin and the CDN returns a cached version.

Comment: Not removed but this specific asset change everytime when a posts is published, but it's just an example since in the whole home page the CDN is not working